# Axios 404 (NOT FOUND) Error in React.js/Node.js Full-Stack Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am building out a full-stack MERN application.  I have a form in the front-end that I want to pass input values on to my back-end for a post to a SQL Server, but I'm getting a 404 (Not Found) Error.  Please let me know if you see anything that might be causing the error.  Thank you, in advance!

**FRONT-END POST CALL TO BACK-END**

```
confirm(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var User = {
    firstName: this.state.firstName,
    lastName: this.state.lastName,
    email: this.state.email,
    password: this.state.password
  };
  instance
    .post("http://localhost:3001/api/signup", {
      User: User
    })
    .then(function (res) {
      alert("Thank you.  You are now registered.");
      window.location.href = "/admin";
      // res.redirect(res, "/admin");
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      alert(error.toJSON());
    });
}
```

**BACK-END**

```
app.post("/api/signup", cors(), function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  sql
    .connect(config)
    .then(() => {
      return sql.query`INSERT INTO fantasy_scrape.dbo.clientele (user_first_name, user_last_name, email, password, join_date) VALUES ('*******', '*******', '****.*******@gmail.com', '*********', GETDATE())`;
    })
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post your full app code in the backend? The frontend seems alright.

Answer (score 0):

try it without putting User in object

```js
 confirm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const User = {
      firstName: this.state.firstName,
      lastName: this.state.lastName,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
        }
        instance.post("http://localhost:3001/api/signup",User).then(function (res) {
        alert("Thank you.  You are now registered.")
        window.location.href="/admin";
        // res.redirect(res, "/admin");
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        alert(error.toJSON());
      });
      };
```